# How to forward with URL parameters in Symfony 1.4 controller?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and i want to forward in my controller to another controller and action with some parameters.

After creating a "bike" with "bike/create" i want to forward to "bike/show/id/X" with the id i got from my new bike instance.

```
$forwardString = 'bike/show/id/'.$bike->id;
$this->forward($url);
```

This does not work :-(

Maybe you can help! :)
Greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method definition for `forward` is `public function forward($module, $action)` the request should be preserved and if theese are things not currently in the request you will have to add them first.

Also you might even need `redirect` instead so the url changes and where you just give it the url `public function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302)` so usage would be `$this->redirect('bike/show?id=' . $bike->id);`

Comment: I would suggest using redirect to avoid F5 Problems.

Comment: is there a way to set redirect sf_method to post?